# gin-gonic templates only ever showing one form

Tags: go, templates, go-gin

I have been setting up my gin templates to use a `base` template that sets out the layout for my various views.

The problem I am having is that all views show my `Register` page, no matter what route I navigate to. All my templates inherit from `base` and define `content` when they are called and are all loaded initially when my application starts with `LoadHTMLGlob()`.

What I expect to see is when each page is visited, the `content` block is inserted into the layout defined in my base template, but on every request I just see the register view.

Looking at the logs, I am getting `200` messages so the routing appears fine, also when I insert some dummy text into the `content` block of `base` it renders fine.

What am I missing below or in general to get this working properly?

Login handler for the `/login` route

```
func getLoginForm(c *gin.Context) {
    c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "login.html", nil)
}
```

Loading templates in `main()`

```
router.LoadHTMLGlob("templates/*") 
router.Static("/public", "./public")
```

base.html

```
{{ define "base" }}

    {{ template "header" .}}
    {{ template "navbar" .}}
    {{ template "flash_messages" .}}

    {{ block "content" .}}
    {{ end }}

    {{ template "footer" .}}

{{ end }}
```

index.html

```
{{ template "base" }}

{{ define "content" }}
    {{ template "site_image" .}}
{{ end }}
```

register.html

```
{{ template "base" }}

{{ define "content" }}
<form method='POST'>
    <br>
    <div class="mb-3"> 
        <label for="email">Email address</label>
        <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3"> 
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input name="username" type="username" class="form-control" id="username"  placeholder="Enter username">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3"> 
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="password"  placeholder="Enter password">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3"> 
        <label for="confirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
        <input name="confirmPassword" type="password" class="form-control" id="confirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>

{{ end }}
```

login.html

```
{{ template "base" }}

{{ define "content" }}
<form method='POST'>
    <br>
    <div class="mb-3"> 
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input name="username" type="username" class="form-control" id="username"  placeholder="Username">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3"> 
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="password"  placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
{{ end }}
```

Comment: Share the handler functions

Comment: There is only one template with the name `content` in the set loaded by `"templates/*"`.  The last one wins.

Comment: @CeriseLimón how do I resolve this issue then?

Comment: give those templates different names, e.g. `login_content`, `register_content`, etc.

Comment: @blackgreen I tried that, but if I do that with the block content, none of them render. If I  create individual blocks for login_content, register_content etc then they all render